# Process POST data in Flask module

Tags: python, flask

I send request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/download/get/` with post data `url=ABCD`.

How i get value `ABCD` in key `url`?

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/download/get/', methods = 'POST')
def get():
    URL = # Something
    return URL
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import request
...
URL = request.form["url"]
```